# How to modify the New Tab page in Firefox with Stylish?

Tags: firefox, stylish

I just upgraded to Firefox 58 after using Chrome for a very long time. I've downloaded Stylish and created the following custom style:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document url-prefix("about:newtab") {
    body {
        background-color: #111111 !important;
    }
}
```

It is saved and enabled, but when I open a new tab Stylish doesn't display any installed styles:

[image]

However, when I switch to any other page, Stylish does show the style I included above:

[image]

Even if I manually navigate to `about:newtab`, the style still does not activate.

So, how do I change the background color of the newtab page in Firefox with Stylish?

Comment: Have you though about using an extension like New Tab Tools? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools/ Also lets you customize new tab in other ways...

Comment: @Clayton Thanks for the suggestion; I'll use that for now although I'd rather figure out what I'm doing wrong with Stylish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Solution on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnaDi_df1eQ)

If author of the vid will delete it , then reupload this vid to Bitchute.com (:D) or read text version of instructions :

1. Type in the adress bar `about:profiles`
2. Open your **ROOT Directory** by clickin "Open directory button". **Not** Local Directory.
3. Create "chrome" directory here by `mkdir chrome` command in terminal or via right click button of your mouse.
4. Open folder that you created and create css file here by naming it "userContent.css"
5. Paste this code to your "userContent.css" file :

   @-moz-document url("about:newtab") {
       body {
           background-color: #000000 !important;
       }
   }
6. Restart your browser manually or by clickin "Restart normally..." button in `about:profiles` adress.

You will get results that you need ! :)

Comment: Thanks; I ended up finding this last night. Accepting this as the answer instead of Clayton's as it does not rely on yet another addon

Comment: Yeah, installing addons makes your browser more unique, that not cool in some aspects.

Comment: Just wanted to add another note: While Firefox is configured to 'show a blank page' on start up, it was not respecting this `userContent.css` file so when I would first open Firefox it would show a white background. What I did to get around this is to set it to 'open my homepage' and then just put `about:newtab` as my homepage

Answer (score 2):

Have you though about using an extension like New Tab Tools? http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools Also lets you customize new tab in other ways...

about:newtab is now considered a browserinternal page by Firefox57+ and therefore extensions like Stylish only have restricted access for security reasons. You can still style it manually by using the userChrome.css
https://www.userchrome.org/what-is-userchrome-css.html