# How to make the about:newtab page black or any other color in Firefox 58?

Tags: firefox

I tried via Stylish extension.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(about:newtab) {*{background-color:#000000;}}
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1288920/how-to-modify-the-new-tab-page-in-firefox-with-stylish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnaDi_df1eQ)

If author of the vid will delete it , then reupload this vid to Bitchute.com (:D) or read text version of instructions :

1. Type in the adress bar `about:profiles`
2. Open your **ROOT Directory** by clickin "Open directory button". **Not** Local Directory.
3. Create "chrome" directory here by `mkdir chrome` command in terminal or via right click button of your mouse.
4. Open folder that you created and create css file here by naming it "userContent.css"
5. Paste this code to your "userContent.css" file :

   @-moz-document url("about:newtab") {
       body {
           background-color: #000000 !important;
       }
   }
6. Restart your browser manually or by clickin "Restart normally..." button in `about:profiles` adress.

You will get results that you need ! :)